# How to make a variable equal to a string of other variables in C

Tags: c

This is the full code, the dig variables are user inputs

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

  int main()
{
    int num;
    int dig1=0;
    int dig2=0;
    int dig3=0;
    num=dig1,dig2,dig3;
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("Please enter the first digit of your three digit number:");
    scanf("%d", &dig1);
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("Please enter the second digit of your three digit number:");
    scanf("%d", &dig2);
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("Please enter the third digit of your three digit number:");
    scanf("%d", &dig3);

    if (num==(dig1*dig1*dig1)+(dig2*dig2*dig2)+(dig3*dig3*dig3))
    {
        printf("Your number is an Armstrong number!\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Your number is not an Armstrong number!\n");
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

How could I make the variable "num" equal to all of the inputs for "dig1", "dig2", and "dig3". As in if dig 1 was 2 and dig 2 was 4 and dig 3 was 6, num would be 246. Please help!

Comment: but how could it be done for every three digit number

Comment: Decimal system is position-weighted by 10, so you'll need to do some multilying by 10...

Comment: All of the answers work for just 2 4 and 6, but all of the dig(s) are user input

Comment: so you rae saying that i should multiply the second and teh thord digits by 10 and 100, as they are the tenths and the hunderths?

Comment: i think that by changing the order of the digs, as in dig 3 comes first then dig2 and dig3 will fix the issue

Answer (score -1):

Your problem can be solved this way:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    int num;
    int dig[3];
    int i,j = 100;
    int result = 0;
    for(i = 0;i<3;i++){
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Please enter the %d digit of your three digit number:",i+1);
        scanf("%d", &dig[i]);
    }

    for(i = 0;i<3;i++){
        result += pow(dig[i],3);
        num += dig[i] * j;
        j/=10;
        printf("%d * %d = %d\n",dig[i],j,num);
    }

    if (num == result)
    {
        printf("Your number is an Armstrong number!\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Your number is not an Armstrong number!\n");
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You could multiply these numbers according to their significant value:

`int num = dig1 + dig2 * 10 + dig3 * 100;`